# Wordpress is adding -1.jpg to all my images. Now they are broken

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited a slightly older Wordpress blog and I updated it, manuallyto version 4.5.3. It has broken all my images.

The path to an example missing image is:

`/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_1280-1.jpg`

Here's the whats in that folder:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge    7100 Feb 26 15:32 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_12801-150x150.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge   22757 Feb 26 15:32 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_12801-300x300.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge    6687 Feb 25 18:21 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_1280-150x150.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge   95613 Feb 26 15:32 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_12801.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge   22153 Feb 25 18:21 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_1280-300x300.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge   75944 Feb 25 18:21 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_1280-624x624.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 forge forge   95613 Feb 25 18:21 tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_1280.jpg`

AFAIK - There should only be 1 image in that folder, I'm not sure at what stage the rest appeared.

Anyone any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm thinking its a wordpress setting? If not I'll need to maybe do a rewrite using nginx to get things working again?

Comment: Wordpress resizes the original image to default sizes and specified sizes. Thats what the images are. Can you post the code that displays the image?

Comment: @peter I've not written any code to handle the images - they've always 'just worked' after being included via the usual posting method? Or did I miss-understand your question?

Comment: How is this image link being generated? `/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/tumblr_n85n0vdFyb1qzj0rpo1_1280-1.jpg`

Comment: Sorry @Peter - I've got you now. Here's the full image tag that is being generated. `<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-382" title="glover" src="https://kiltmakers.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/glover-1.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="376" srcset="https://kiltmakers.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/glover-1.jpg 400w, https://kiltmakers.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/glover-1-300x282.jpg 300w" sizes="(max-width: 400px) 100vw, 400px">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the code that generates the src's for the images and wrote a reg'ex to remove the offending "-1" from the URLs. Not an ideal solution but its got me by for now.